# Size limitation when using a texture as a render target

Tags: c#, directx, slimdx

I want to create a texture and to render to its surface but I have a problem: When the texture size is to big (more than 263x263 pixel ARGB), no primitive is rendered in the surface (I just can see the color used during the *Clear* operation).

Here is my code:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Setting up DirectX
        PresentParameters pp = new PresentParameters()
        {
            BackBufferCount = 1,
            Windowed = true,
            SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard,
            BackBufferWidth = ClientSize.Width,
            BackBufferHeight = ClientSize.Height,
        };

        d3d = new Direct3D();
        device = new Device(d3d, 0, DeviceType.Hardware, Handle, CreateFlags.HardwareVertexProcessing, pp);

        TexturedVertex.SetVertexDeclaration(device);

        // Creating a triangle
        triangleBuffer = new VertexBuffer(device, 3 * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TexturedVertex)), Usage.WriteOnly, VertexFormat.None, Pool.Managed);

        var stream1 = triangleBuffer.Lock(0, 0, LockFlags.None);
        stream1.WriteRange(new[] {
                            new TexturedVertex( -2, -2, 0, 0, 0 ),
                            new TexturedVertex( 0, 2, 0, 1, 0),
                            new TexturedVertex( 2, -2, 0, 1, 1),
                    });

        triangleBuffer.Unlock();

        // Creating a rect
        rectBuffer = new VertexBuffer(device, 4 * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TexturedVertex)), Usage.WriteOnly, VertexFormat.None, Pool.Managed);

        var stream2 = rectBuffer.Lock(0, 0, LockFlags.None);
        stream2.WriteRange(new[] {
                            new TexturedVertex( -2, -2, 0, 0, 0 ),
                            new TexturedVertex( -2, 2, 0, 0, 1),
                            new TexturedVertex( 2, -2, 0, 1, 0),
                            new TexturedVertex( 2, 2, 0, 1, 1),
                    });

        TexturedVertex.SetVertexDeclaration(device);
        rectBuffer.Unlock();

        // Creating a render texture
        int w = 262;
        Texture texture = new Texture(device, w, w, 0, Usage.RenderTarget, Format.A8R8G8B8, Pool.Default);

        Surface surface = texture.GetSurfaceLevel(0);
        Surface buffer = device.GetRenderTarget(0);

        device.SetRenderTarget(0, surface);

        device.SetTransform(TransformState.Projection, Matrix.OrthoOffCenterLH(-4, 4, -4, 4, 0, 100));
        device.SetTransform(TransformState.View, Matrix.Identity);
        device.SetTransform(TransformState.World, Matrix.Identity);

        device.Clear(ClearFlags.Target, new Color4(Color.Green), 0, 0);

        device.BeginScene();

        device.SetStreamSource(0, triangleBuffer, 0, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TexturedVertex)));
        device.DrawPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleStrip, 0, 3);

        device.EndScene();
        device.Present();

        device.SetRenderTarget(0, buffer);

        // Setting current texture and material
        device.SetTexture(0, texture);
        Material mat = new Material();
        mat.Ambient = mat.Diffuse = mat.Emissive = Color.White;
        device.Material = mat;

        // Setting the projection, view and transform matrix
        device.SetTransform(TransformState.Projection, Matrix.OrthoOffCenterLH(-4, 4, -4, 4, 0, 100));
        device.SetTransform(TransformState.View, Matrix.Identity);
        device.SetTransform(TransformState.World, Matrix.Identity);


        // Setting handler
        this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyDown);
        this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Form1_Paint);
    }

    void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        device.Clear(ClearFlags.Target, new Color4(Color.Purple), 0, 0);

        device.BeginScene();

        device.SetStreamSource(0, rectBuffer, 0, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TexturedVertex)));
        //device.SetStreamSource(0, triangleBuffer, 0, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TexturedVertex)));

        device.DrawPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleStrip, 0, 4);

        device.EndScene();

        device.Present();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your form's client size is 262 pixel wide or high.

In the presentational parameters you limit your backbuffer and z buffer to this size. You need another Z buffer, matching the size of the texture you want to render, and you need to set it to be used, and then switched back to the original.

```
Surface oldDepthBuffer = device.DepthStencilSurface;
Texture db = new Texture(device, w, w, 1, Usage.DepthStencil, oldDepthBuffer.Description.Format, Pool.Default);

Surface myDepthBuffer = db.GetSurfaceLevel(0);

device.SetRenderTarget(0, surface);
device.DepthStencilSurface = myDepthBuffer;

// RENDER to texture

device.DepthStencilSurface = oldDepthBuffer;
```

Comment: I found another way: removing the z buffer that I don't use did the trick: *pp.EnableAutoDepthStencil = false*

Comment: I try your edit and it work too: I can keep the use of the z buffer, thanks!!

Comment: I finaly end up with your solution because disabling depth buffer reduce multisampling quality when drawing primitive (I don't know why...)

Comment: Multisampling is not oversampling the whole image, it first checks if the depth of a subpixel is different from the others, and if it does, then it takes multiple samples from them. It is possible that without depth buffer it cannot check for depth differences and does not get multiple samples, hence the quality loss.